# Determine intersection of a circle's perimeter with another circle's area in C#, when circle areas and perimeters are integer Vector2s

Tags: c#, optimization, geometry

Wrote a short method that determine the intersection of two circles (intersection of Circle A's perimeter with Circle B's area). The areas and perimeters of each circle are integer `List<Vector2>`s, so I'm basically looking for overlap between points. (These will get translated to pixels on a bitmap later).

In this case, the center of Circle A will always reside on the perimeter of Circle B. I have a method already that determines it, but quickly gets very expensive if I'm dealing with a larger circle.

The perimeter and area fields of a Circle object are `List<Vector2>` type.

```
public List<Vector2> CalculateIntersection()
        {
            List<Vector2> perimeterIntersection = new List<Vector2>();
            for(int i = 0; i < CircleA.perimeter.Count; i ++)
            {
                if (CircleB.area.Exists(query => query.Equals(CircleA.perimeter[i])))
                {
                    perimeterIntersection.Add(CircleA.perimeter[i]);
                }
            }
            return perimeterIntersection;
        }
```

So I'm just looking to see if there is any, perhaps easier or computationally cheaper way to do an equivalent process. Perhaps some obscure geometric law that relates to this subject that I'm unaware of? Anything would help, thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: That link helps, thanks!